# How to select the date from Bootstrap Glyphicon date picker using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, datepicker, webdriver

Below is my html `DOM` of my date picker.In this Input filed is non-editable.There is no other 'tr' 'td' tags in DOM for  date picker.

```html
<form>
<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
    <input type="text" id="accFromDateId" class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MMM/YYYY" data-i18n="BillsView.CustomerSearch.Placeholder.DateFormat">
    <span class="input-group-addon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> </span> </div></form>
```

This Input field is only taking the date from the date picker .
I tried the below code. but it won't work

Selenium Script:

```
WebElement date=driver.findElement(By.name("accFromDateId"));
date.sendKeys("01232019"); 
date.submit();
```

Comment: can share the screen shot of that disable fields

Comment: Where is the HTML?

Comment: @akshaypatil Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider suggesting OP to update the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

1)Find by 'ID' should have been used instead of 'Name'

```
 var driver = new ChromeDriver();
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("demo.html");
 IWebElement date = driver.FindElement(By.Id("accFromDateId"));
 date.SendKeys("01232019");
 date.Submit();
```

2)The alternative approach would be to work with datepicker popup. Find a sample code below that picks jquery datepicker

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/");
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[@class='demo-frame']")));
IWebElement date = driver.FindElement(By.Id("datepicker"));
date.Click();
driver.FindElementByLinkText("24").Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question why you find *Input filed also non-editable*. To send a character sequence i.e. *date* as **25/JAN/2019** through the `<input>` tag you can use the following solution:

```
WebElement myDate = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='form-control' and @id='accFromDateId']")));
myDate.clear();
myDate.sendKeys("25/JAN/2019"); 
myDate.submit();
```